# Вытащить данные с URL с помощью backbone.js

Tags: json, backbone.js

Здравствуйте!

Мне требуется вытащить данные (текущее время) с этого сайта: http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json

Подскажите, как это сделать для формата json, 
я пробовал таким способом, но ничего не получилось:

```
Route::get('/http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json', function() {
    $fetchTasks = Mission::all();
    $fetchedModels = array();

    foreach ($fetchTasks as $model) {
        $fetchedModels[]=$model->attributes;
    }

    return json_encode($fetchedModels);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$get = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json'), true);

echo $get['datetime']; // Fri, 12 Dec 2014 15:31:47 +0000
```